# Jetty - Add JDBC session clustering

Tags: java, jetty

I'm trying to add session clustering in jetty and haven't been succcessfull. tried different article and solutions. Below are my trials. Any help is greatly appreciated

Trial 1

Adding --module=jdbc-sessions in start.ini didn't work. Say a warning that jdbc-sessions is not a valid module
java -jar ../start.jar
WARNING: Cannot enable requested module [jdbc-sessions]: not a valid module name.

Trial 2
Tried adding --add-to-startd while starting jetty. It didn't add jdbc-sessions to start.ini file.

Jetty version:jetty-distribution-9.2.15

Answer (score 2):

JDBC Sessions were not managed by the Jetty Module system until Jetty 9.3. Documentation for how to implement JDBC Sessions in Jetty 9.2 can be found [here](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.10.v20150310/session-clustering-jdbc.html). If you wanted to you could create your own JDBC module using the templates shown [here](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.10.v20150310/startup-modules.html).

On a side note, I would recommend upgrading your Jetty distribution unless you have a compelling reason to stay with 9.2. Jetty 9.4 has a milestone release out already and a full release is expected in the next month or two.